# How can I check if a hive table is partitioned or not programatically?

Tags: pyspark, hive

How can I find out if a hive table is partitioned or not programatically and by not going into the beeline shell and checking the partition column.
is there any way to check this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `describe detail`  sql statement in **`spark.sql`**.

**`Example:`**

```
spark.sql("describe detail <db_name>.<tab_name>").select("partitionColumns").show()
```

---

For **non partitioned** table query results empty **`array<>`**

```
+----------------+
|partitionColumns|
+----------------+
|              []|
+----------------+
```

---

For **partitioned** table query results an **`array<>`** that includes partition column names.

```
+-------------------+
|   partitionColumns|
+-------------------+
|[load_date]|
+-------------------+
```